# Docker on Yosemite OSX: Add host "boot2docker" and starting

Tags: macos, boot2docker, docker-machine

On Yosemite OSX, I need some assistance of adding a host "boot2docker" and then starting docker machine using this host.

Initially, I was trying to resolve TLS warnings after the following line within my .bash_profile script ran:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env boot2docker)"
```

Reading through other postings, it recommended rm and then adding "boot2docker", so I did this, remove "boot2docker" host, and now I forget how to add this host back:

```
docker-machine rm boot2docker
```

So now I am getting a new error:

```
Host does not exist: "boot2docker"
```

I have Docker install and default does run

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.11.0
$ docker-machine status
Running
```

The boot2docker.iso is found within my home directory;

```
ls -al .boot2docker/
total 65536
drwxr-xr-x   5 jefft  staff       170 Feb 18 13:58 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 41 jefft  staff      1394 Apr 18 09:32 ..
srwxr-xr-x   1 jefft  staff         0 Feb 18 13:58 boot2docker-vm.sock
-rw-r--r--   1 jefft  staff  33554432 Feb 18 13:57 boot2docker.iso
drwxr-xr-x   3 jefft  staff       102 Feb 18 13:58 certs
```

How can I re-add Host "boot2docker" back and then once that is done get past the TLS warnings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I only need to do the following, and I was fine:

```
docker-machine create boot2docker
```